# How do I retrieve current chaincode version in Hyperledger Fabric?

Tags: bash, docker, hyperledger-fabric

I'm writing a script for upgrading chaincode. I would like to read the old chaincode version and increase it for the new install.

**Is there a way to retrieve a chaincode version from peer containers?**

Answer (score 2):

Simple way is using CLI by execute `peer` command:

If you using Fabric version 1.x:

```
peer chaincode list --instantiated -C <your_channel_name>
```

Fabric 2.x:

```
peer lifecycle chaincode querycommitted -C <your_channel_name>
```